# Hovering over the products moves my <footer>

Tags: html, css

I have a project for a course on coursera. This is part of the course is focusing on CSS animations. I added a hover effect over my product class and the hover effects works but it moves my footer. I would love to keep the hover effect. Is there anyway to prevent it from moving the ? Also would like to know if there was a way that I could make the image in my banner class change colors without having to hover over it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="sandbox.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="sandbox.scss">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <header>
        <img src="data:image/png;base64,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" class="banner"  alt="logo">
    </header>
</div>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="#cards">Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#info">Info</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<main>
    <section class="banner">
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/02/14/09/45/diamond-1199183_1280.jpg"  height="556px">
        <div id="info">
            <h1>MANGATA & GALLO</h1>
            <p>Mariana is the owner and the lead designer of Mangata and Gallo. After graduating from design school with a specialization in diamond cutting and metal smithing, Mariana opened a store in her hometown, Austin and started to grow her business online. Mariana has always managed every aspect of the business, from jewelry design to marketing to e-commerce. However, she recently hired several artisans to help craft her designs and a young employee to help manage the company website and social media accounts.</p>
        </div>
        
<section id="cards">
    <article class="product">
        <h3 class="card-title">Wedding rings</h3>
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTirprNMUJgd2fFMXWpwgs4GRao7zGDsQSfeA&usqp=CAU" alt="">
        <p class="card-description">Array of wedding rings that are perfect for your happily ever after.</p>
    </article>
    <article class="product">
        <h3 class="card-title">Necklace</h3>
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQd3aEgJxlBw_XudR9uytYeBrNjFpAbc07l3Q&usqp=CAU" alt="">
        <p class="card-description">Elegant necklaces, perfect for a fashionable woman.</p>
    </article>
    <article class="product">
        <h3 class="card-title">Bracelets</h3>
        <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" alt="">
        <p class="card-description">Take a look at the timeless gemstones that sparkle on our bracelets. </p>
    </article>
</section>
</main>
<footer>
    <div>
        <img src="data:image/png;base64,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" class="footer-image" width="200px" height="50px" alt="">
    </div>
    <div>
        <p class="copyright">Copyright Mangata and Gallo Jewelry. &copy; 2024 All rights reserved.</p>
    </div>
</footer>
</body>
</html>



 CSS

  * {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
margin-top: 10px;
}

header {
display: flex;
justify-content: center
}

nav {
display: block;
margin-top: 10px;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
background-color: black;
}

nav ul {
list-style: none;
line-height: 50px;
margin: 10px;
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
}

nav > ul > li {
display: inline-block;
border: 2px solid;
border-radius: 20px;
width: 150px;
text-align: center;
font-size: 30px;
margin-right: 25px;
}

a {
   color: white;
}

li > a {
text-decoration: none;

}

nav > ul > li:hover {
color: black;
box-shadow: 3px 3px rgb(25, 0, 75);
animation: change .8s infinite alternate ;
}

nav > ul > li:hover > a {
color: black
}

a:active {
text-shadow: 0 0 30px rgb(36, 35, 35), 0 0 5px rgb(101, 100, 100);
 }

main {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
background-color: black;
}


@keyframes change {
from{
    background-color: white;
} 
to {
    background-color: rgb(78, 78, 201);
}
}

@keyframes changepro {
0% {
    background-color: blue;
}
25% {
    background-color: green;
}
50%{
    background-color: red;
}
100% {
    background-color: rgb(78, 78, 201);
}

}

.banner{
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
}

.banner img{
width: 100%;
}

#info{
text-align: center;
max-width: 800px;
position: absolute;
top: 430px;
left: 250px;
color: white;
padding: 10px;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.594);
}

h1{
text-decoration: underline;
font-size: 30px;
}

p{
margin-top: 10px;
font-size: 20px;
color: white;
}

#cards {
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 33.3% 33.3% 33.3%;
margin-left: 140px;
padding-top: 20px;
}

#cards img {
width: 180px;
height: 140px;
margin-left: 10px;
border-radius: 15px;
}

.product {
width: 200px;
color: white;
border-radius: 15px;
padding-top: 5px;
}

.product:hover {
animation: changepro 4s infinite alternate;
box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 5px  rgb(37, 13, 49);
transform: scale(1.1);
border: 2px solid navy
}

.product img{
margin-left: 5px;
}

.card-title {
text-align: center;
padding-bottom: 2px;
}
.card-description {
text-align: center;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}

footer {
background-color: black;
padding-top: 25px;
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
}

.footer-image {
margin-left: 380px;
}

.copyright {
font-size: 15px;
padding-top: 12px;
width: 400px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are experiencing that is because of the `border` you specified in `.product:hover`

```css
.product:hover {
animation: changepro 4s infinite alternate;
box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 5px  rgb(37, 13, 49);
transform: scale(1.1);
/* border: 2px solid navy */
}
```